# Invertiblity of $ST$ and Invertibility of $TS$ imply each other

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ where $V$ is *finite-dimensional* $ST=I$ if and only if $TS=I$.

**Proof.** ($\Rightarrow$). Assume that $ST=I$ it is apparent that $ST
\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ now let $v$ be arbitrary and assume that $v\in\operatorname{null}ST$ consequently 
$$STv = Iv=v=0$$
this implies that $\operatorname{null} ST=\{0\}$ and therefore $ST$ is injective moreover from the equivalence of *injectivity* and is *surjectivity* for linear operators on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ it follows that $ST$ is invertible this together with $\mathbf{3-D-9}$ implies that both $S$ and $T$ are invertible consequently
$$ST = I \implies TST = TI=T\implies TS(TT^{-1})=TT^{-1}\implies TS=I.$$
$(\Leftarrow).$ The converse will involve a similar argument to that present above.

NOTE: $\mathbf{3-D-9}$ is the following result

> Given that $V$ is *finite-dimensional* and $S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. $ST$ is invertible if and only if both $S$ and $T$ are invertible.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: What is 3-D-9? Looks like a straight copy and paste from some textbook. Could you give a reference?

Comment: Technically it is correct, but you don't really need to prove that $ST=I$ is invertible...

Comment: Should i then just state that it is self evident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity operator $I:V\to V$ is invertible, and so is $ST.$ Now $ST$ is invertible, so both $S$ and $T$ is invertible. Assume that $ST=I.$ Then $T=S^{-1}\implies TS=S^{-1}S=I.$